Can I use this old LG as an android tv?
I have an old monitor that is still working ok (LG W2361V).
Is it possible to make it into a TV by using an android box or is it too old for that? What about the sound?

Please read the tags before posting your question. You are asking an off-topic question. See [help/on-topic].
